# Nested tables in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Since there is no option to merge table cells in Google docs, creating a new table inside a cell could be a possible work around for this.

When I insert a table inside a table cell, blank lines are inserted before and after the table. How can I remove these blank lines? or create a layout similar to the one shown in the picture below (without the extra lines in first column)

[image: Nested table in Google Docs]

I have tried playing around with cell padding and minimum row height in table properties but found no solution.

Comment: Actually it is now possible to merge cells in Docs: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141104?hl=en

Comment: @filipeglfw - How does merging help the situation?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it's not possible to remove the line before and after the nested table. The good "news" are that now is possible to merge cells.

**References**
[Add and edit tables - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1696711?hl=en)
[Merge cells and wrap text - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141104?hl=en)

Comment: How does merging help?

Answer (score 2):

**How does merging help?**

To create complex table structures, starting from the most nested cells you will need and merge cells to achieve the larger cells.

Example:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+

+--------------+
|              |
+--+-----+-----+
|  |     |     |
+--+-----+     +
|        |     |
+-----+--+--+--+
|     |     |  |
+-----+--------+
```