# Strange spacing issue in Google Document?

Tags: google-docs

I found this nice clean CV Google Docs template [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ARVyybC5qQEiCzUOLElwAdPpKOK0Qf88srr682eHdCQ/edit#heading=h.ymi089liagec).

I would like to replace the name by a 2-column table that includes a name.

The problem is, that I cannot remove the space above or below the table. This is the space that I would like to allocate for the table:

[image]

Here is a link to the document with the [table](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hn_2wVetUNqIcPxgaWdV_PRVNNIPVs_elqMh_quyKvQ/edit).

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgu-fUUuB64&feature=youtu.be) how I failed to increase the table size. I also found some invisible lines, not sure how they effect the document.

Any suggestions how to increse the table size to the red borders?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're experiencing is the same as described [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54132/nested-tables-in-google-docs).

Everything in that document is contained in a big table. You can't see the table, because the table has a border of zero and a border color of white. If you try to create another table inside this one it adds space to the top and bottom of the cell of the big table.

[This](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MtxQd6E8Nb_udVHtIzSbpelA8Gbicx5bAWNX0nPrif0/edit?usp=sharing) is my edit of your document.

I used the solution suggested in the post I linked. I created an extra column and merged where there should only be 1 column. The table still has a border of zero and border color of white except for the 2 columns you wanted to include. I selected those cells and gave them a black border with a border width of 1.